# Using Python to solve a 5th order polynomial

Tags: python, syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I think it is pretty clear from the title as to what I am trying to accomplish. So, let us get on with the code:

```
import math

import numpy as np

import scipy

#from scipy import scipy.optimize.fsolve as sci_solve



x0 = -5

def function(x):

    x**5 + x**4 + x**3 + x**2 + x + 1

#print sci_solve(function, x0)

print scipy.optimize.fsolve(function, x0)
```

Okay, so when I run this code, I get [-5.]. When did it simply print my initial value, and not the roots of this equation? Also, when I ran the code without # before the lines containing the code #from scipy import scipy.optimize.fsolve as sci_solve and print sci_solve(function, x0), it gave me a syntax error.

What am I doing wrong?

As hcwhsa points out, I neglected to relate to the reader the version of python I am using, and I am terribly sorry for this. I am using version 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd never actually heard of the `scipy` module before this question (so thank you for that), but from the example code given at http://folk.uio.no/inf3330/scripting/doc/python/SciPy/tutorial/old/node18.html, it appears that you need to put a `return` statement before the polynomial given in after the line `def function(x):`.

Comment: Okay, that helped somewhat. Rather than returning the x0 value, it returned [-1.]. However, I can't imagine that this is the only root to the equation 0 = x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1

Comment: See this [Wolfram Alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x**5%2Bx**4%2Bx**3%2Bx**2%2Bx%2B1).  -1 is the only (real) solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

```
from scipy import *

x0 = -5
p = poly1d([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# evaluate for x = x0
p(x0)

# get roots
roots(p)
```

This gives you all roots, including complex ones. If you want only real roots, you can iterate over roots(p) (it's an array) and check that each item's `imag` attribute is 0.0.